# How can I customize the size of navigation buttons in Swiper (Angular)

Tags: angular, swiper.js

In my current project, the Swiper navigation buttons are too large, but I don't know how to manipulate the size.

I've tried this in the styles.css file:

```
::ng-deep .swiper-button-prev:after,
::ng-deep .swiper-button-next:after {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

But it doesn't work for me.

I know I can open the file **swiper-bundle.css** and correct this line:

```
:root {
  --swiper-navigation-size: 44px;
}
```

But this file is located inside a npm package, meaning changes made in that file is **local** only. I need to push my code to GitHub, so that solution doesn't count.

Comment: Aren't you able to overwrite the root variable in your `styles.css`? `:root {
  --swiper-navigation-size: 44px; // change this value
}`

Comment: I've tried your solution. Now it works, but remember to put "src/styles.css" after "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" in angular.json file.

Answer (score 4):

```
  <Swiper
                    style={{
                      "--swiper-navigation-color": "#000",
                      "--swiper-navigation-size": "25px",
                    }}
                    slidesPerView={matchesSmall ? 5 : 8}
                    spaceBetween={30}
                    centeredSlides={true}
                    freeMode={true}
                    navigation={false}
                    watchSlidesProgress={true}
                    modules={[FreeMode, Navigation]}
                  >
                   ...
                  </Swiper>
```

use style props

Answer (score 0):

```
 ::ng-deep .swiper-button-prev:after,
 ::ng-deep .swiper-button-next:after {
   --swiper-navigation-size: 15px;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**